# THREE.something not recognized in Brackets

Tags: javascript, three.js, adobe-brackets

my code is:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh;
var x, y, z;

function init() {
    "use strict";
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    scene = new THREE.scene();

    function createplanet() {

        var colorget, geometry;
        function randomcolor() {
            var letters, color, i;
            color = '#';
            letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
            i = 1;
            if (i === true) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }

        geometry = new window.THREE.SphereGeometry(x, y, z);
        x = Math.random() * 3;
        y = Math.random() * 10;
        z = y;

        colorget = new window.THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: randomcolor()
                                              });
}
}


init();
animate();
```

Note: I'll add an animate function later.

My question is that whenever I try to use the live preview ability of Brackets, nothing shows up and I think it's because THREE.something isn't recognized in Brackets. I have downloaded three.js so should I use a JSON file or what? Also, any other help with any issues that you notice would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML file (the one that calls this JavaScript code or has it embedded within), you should reference your three.js file.

For example if it is located in a `scripts` folder, you would type `<script src="scripts/three.js"></script>`.

**Important:** This line must go above the line(s) that call *your* JavaScript code that you quoted above.

Comment: Can you use <script src="filename"></script> or would you have to put in all of the sections individually?

Comment: Actually, I just got it to work but now it's only showing a black screen. Can you help me with that because I think it's the code shown this time. If so, I'd be incredibly grateful

Comment: You should start a new question if this is what you would like, detailing the issue. Could you please accept my answer if it solved the original problem.